# c++ out of range at memory location error

Tags: c++, memory

Here is the code I have for a programing assignment I have. Im getting this error when I run the program 
"Unhandled exception at at 0x772BC41F in STRUCT2.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0043ED04." If I understand this right, the error means my array has exceeded the allotted memory space. is that correct? and if this is correct, what am I doing wrong? My input file has less than 30 elements in it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
 using namespace std;

struct Element
{
string Name;
char eN1;
char eN2;
float Weight;
};

struct Formula
{
char Element1;
char ElementA;
int Atom;
 };

void ELEMENTS(Element ElmAry[30]);
float Str2Float(string Weight);
void FORMULAS(Formula FormAry[30]);
float CalculateMoleculeWeight(Element ElmAry[30], Formula FormAry[30]);

int main()
{
ifstream inputFile1;
ifstream inputFile2;
ofstream outputFile;

inputFile1.open("Element.txt");
inputFile2.open("Formula.txt");
outputFile.open("Molecular Weight.txt");

Element ElmAry[30];
Formula FormAry[30];
char inputCh;
int i = 0;
string String1;
string mFor;
string ABRV;
int ElmDigit = 0;
float StringWeight = 0;
string Name;
string Weight;
int LENGTH = 0;
float MOLEWT;


if(!inputFile1)
{
    cout << "Couldn't find the Element.txt file." << endl;
    return 0;
}

if(!inputFile2)
{
    cout << "Couldn't find the Formula.txt file." << endl;
    return 0;
}

ELEMENTS(ElmAry);

while(inputFile1)
{
    Name = String1.substr(0,2);
    ElmAry[i].Name = Name;

    Weight = String1.substr(3,10);
    String1.clear();
    StringWeight = Str2Float(Weight);
    ElmAry[i].Weight = StringWeight;
    i++;
}
i--;

FORMULAS(FormAry);

while (inputFile2)
{
    getline(inputFile2,String1);
    LENGTH = String1.length();
    int j = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while( j < LENGTH)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        pos = String1.find(')');
        while(n < LENGTH)
        {
            inputCh = String1.at(n);
            if(isalpha(inputCh) && isupper(inputCh))
            {
                FormAry[j].Element1 = String1.at(n);
                n++;
                inputCh = String1.at(n);
            }

            if(isalpha(inputCh) && islower(inputCh))
            {
                FormAry[j].ElementA = String1.at(n);
                n++;
                inputCh = String1.at(n);
            }

            if(ispunct(inputCh))
            {
                n++;
                inputCh = String1.at(n);
                ElmDigit = (inputCh-'0');
            }

            if(isdigit(inputCh))
            {
                FormAry[j].Atom = ElmDigit;
                n++;
            }
            inputCh = String1.at(n);

            j++;

            if(iscntrl(inputCh))
            {
                n++;
                inputCh = String1.at(n);
                j++;
            }
            n++;
        }
    }
}

MOLEWT = CalculateMoleculeWeight(ElmAry, FormAry);

cout << "\t\t MOLECULAR WEIGHT CHART \t\t\n" << endl;
cout << "\n| FORMULA |\t " << "\t| ATOM.WT |" << endl;
cout << "_______________________________";
outputFile << "\t\t MOLECULAR WEIGHT CHART \t\t\n" << endl;
outputFile << "\n| FORMULA |\t " << "\t| ATOM.WT |" << endl;
outputFile << "_______________________________";

for (int a = 0; a < 30; a++)
{
    cout << MOLEWT << endl;
    outputFile << MOLEWT << endl;
}

inputFile1.close();
inputFile2.close();
outputFile.close();
cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}

void ELEMENTS(Element ElmAry[30])
{
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    ElmAry[i].Weight = 0;
}
}

void FORMULAS(Formula FormAry[30])

{
for(int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        FormAry[x].Atom = 1;
    }
}

}

float Str2Float (string x)
{
    stringstream ss(x);
    float StringWeight;
    ss >> StringWeight;
    return StringWeight;
}

float CalculateMoleculeWeight(Element ElmAry[30], Formula FormAry[30])
{
int i;
int j=0;
float MoleWT = 0;
float MoleSum = 0;
char e1;
char e2;
char f1;
char f2;

    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        f1 = FormAry[j].Element1;
        f2 = FormAry[j].ElementA;
        e1 = ElmAry[i].eN1;
        e2 = ElmAry[i].eN1;
        if
            (e1 == f1 && e2 == f2)
    {
        MoleWT = ElmAry[i].Weight * FormAry[j].Atom;
        MoleSum = MoleSum + MoleWT;
        j++;
    }
}
return MoleSum;
}
```

when I get to

```
 while(inputFile1)
 {
    Name = String1.substr(0,2);
    ElmAry[i].Name = Name;

    Weight = String1.substr(3,10);//invalid string position
    String1.clear();
    StringWeight = Str2Float(Weight);
    ElmAry[i].Weight = StringWeight;
    i++;
}
i--;
```

Weight = String1.substr(3,10); gives me an invalid string position

Comment: Holy code dump, Batman!

Comment: Way too much code. Put some effort in and narrow your problem down.

Comment: Run it under a debugger.  Find out where it AV's.  Fix it.

Comment: In your second extract of code, you haven't initialized `String1` to anything, no wonder it's giving you an error, it's empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::out_of_range` is an exception you get when you attempt to access memory outside the space you've allocated (in an STL container).  In this particular case, you are accessing areas of a `std::string` that has not been allocated:

```
Weight = String1.substr(3,10); // empty string or string.length() < 4 throws here
```

`std::string::substr` takes index parameters that must be within the bounds of the array encapsulated by `std::string`.  If the string is only 2 characters long, and you attempt to get characters starting at the 4th position, you will see the `std::out_of_range` exception.  You should check the `length` prior to doing this kind of operation.

Additionally, you are declaring your arrays:

```
Element ElmAry[30];
Formula FormAry[30];
```

But you are looping through an entire file (which potentially has more than 30 elements).  Thus, when `i >= 30`, you are out of bounds (and behavior will be undefined).

You can fix that by using `std::vector`, which will allow the array to be dynamically sized, or another collection (e.g. `std::list`, `std::deque`).

Comment: Legacy C arrays do **not** throw `out_of_range`, when you go past the end it just invokes UB. `std::string::substr(3, 10)` on an empty string is a much more likely candidate (especially since OP *does* say this is where the error happens).

Comment: @syam:  He hadn't added that piece yet ... will update to account for that.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't pay attention to the post/edit times. But still, C arrays never throw, your answer is plain wrong currently. As PaulGriffiths pointed out in a comment, the error is because OP never puts anything in the string.

Comment: @syam:  Not entirely.  Even with C arrays, building in Debug (in VS) would throw a runtime exception, but in general, yes.  Adjusted the answer to be more accurate.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but your description of `substr` is wrong too. `out_of_range` is only thrown if `pos` (the first argument) is strictly greater than the string's size. The count (second argument) is simply clamped if `(pos + count) > size()`. So the first call `substr(0, 2)` will always succeed even on an empty string. [See this doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). As to VS throwing in debug mode, they are allowed to do that because the operation is UB in the first place, but that's definitely not part of the C++ specification.

Comment: `Name = String1.substr(0,2);` won't cause a problem on an empty string, it'll treat that `2` as a maximum.

Comment: My mistake ... fixed.

Comment: so any suggestions oh how to fix this?

Comment: Check to make sure the length is longer than the position you are attempting to start your substring.